# Foreign key query error in case of custom uint64 field which was used as a primary key

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, peewee

I needed uint64 field as primary key field for my database, expectedly other models used foreign key to point to this model. Resulting code was something like this:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('test.db')

class UInt64(Field):
    db_field = 'bigint'

    def db_value(self, value):
        return value - (1<<63)

    def python_value(self, value):
        return value + (1<<63)

class Foo(Model):
    id = UInt64(primary_key = True)

    class Meta:
        database = db

class Bar(Model):
    id = UInt64(primary_key = True)
    foo = ForeignKeyField(Foo, related_name='bars')
```

This code works properly for all requests used by me expect one:

```
>>> f = Foo.create(id=10000)
>>> Bar.create(id=123, foo=f)
<ptest.Bar object at 0x7f2fde7f7e10>
>>> b = Bar.get()
>>> b.id
123
>>> b.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 1151, in __get__
    return self.get_object_or_id(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 1142, in get_object_or_id
    obj = self.rel_model.get(self.field.to_field == rel_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 4403, in get
    return sq.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2812, in get
    return clone.execute().next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2859, in execute
    self._qr = ResultWrapper(model_class, self._execute(), query_meta)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2555, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3359, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER
```

It seems that somewhere conversion between python value and db value was not done properly. Looks like a bug to me.

Any ideas how it can be fixed without directly saving foo id in Bar as UInt64 instead of use of ForeignKeyField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in peewee, which is now fixed:
https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/791

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the Python sqlite driver you're using. It's trying to cast to an int and overflowing.